# React js page reload 404 eror using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi i am using react js and react-router-dom for routing.My issue is that when i reload the page i gets below error on browser.my code works fine local server. but on live server i got below error.

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

here is my htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

here is my routing file

```
import React from "react";
// Importing Routing Library
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
// Importing Layouts Files
import MainLayout from "src/layouts/MainLayout";
import DashboardLayout from "src/layouts/DashboardLayout";
import ErrorLayout from "src/layouts/ErrorLayout";
// Importing View Files
import NotFoundView from "src/views/errors/NotFoundView";
import LoginView from "src/views/auth/LoginView";
import DashboardView from "src/views/app/DashboardView";
import { AddInstallView } from "src/views/app/Install/AddInstallView";
import { NewInstallView } from "src/views/app/Install/NewInstallView";
import { ExistInstallView } from "src/views/app/Install/ExistInstallView";
import { UpdateInstallView } from "src/views/app/Install/UpdateInstallView";
import { SuccessView } from "src/views/app/Install/SuccessView";

const routes = (loggedIn) => {
  //alert(loggedIn);
  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/*",
      exact: true,
      element: <Navigate to="/auth/login" />,
    },
    {
      path: "/app",
      element: loggedIn ? <DashboardLayout /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />,
      children: [
        { path: "/dashboard", element: <DashboardView /> },
        { path: "/install/add", element: <AddInstallView /> },
        { path: "/install/add/new", element: <NewInstallView /> }, 
        { path: "/install/list", element: <ExistInstallView /> },
        { path: "/replacement", element: <UpdateInstallView /> }, 
        { path: "/success", element: <SuccessView /> },
        { path: "/*", element: <Navigate to="/error/404" /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "/auth",
      element: !loggedIn ? <MainLayout /> : <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" />,
      children: [
        { path: "/login", element: <LoginView /> },
        { path: "/*", element: <Navigate to="/error/404" /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "/error",
      element: <ErrorLayout />,
      children: [
        { path: "/404", element: <NotFoundView /> },
        { path: "/*", element: <Navigate to="/error/404" /> },
      ],
    },
  ];
  return routes;
};

export default routes;
```

What is the solution for this??

Comment: You hosted on firebase?

Comment: How do you implement the Navigate component? Is it using props.history? It is possible that the path always resolves to 404 because of the wild card *.

Comment: @NihalChandwani no it is appache server

Comment: @iismaell i have  implement the Navigate component like this navigate("/app/dashboard")